# In "The Matrix Revolutions" How Does Neo Stop the Machine Weapons in the Real World?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions*, when Neo and Trinity are trying to get to the Machine City, when the Machines launch weapons against them, Neo is able to destroy some of the incoming weapons.

This is in the real world at this point, not in the Matrix.  How does Neo have any powers against the machines outside of the Matrix?

Addendum: I'm looking for **in universe** answers only.  I would think that would be obvious, but I'm adding this after an answer that is essentially, "It's a movie..."

Comment: What makes you so sure it's the real world, and not just one level closer to the real world?  ;)

Comment: @Izkata: If that's what you think, why not make a good case for it and make it your answer?

Comment: It's turtles all the way down! :)

Comment: Wi-fi, the one is someone who's implants can connect wirelessly.

Comment: @TangoOversway It _was_ just a semi-sarcastic comment with no real case, but I have remembered something...  Gimme a few minutes  =D

Comment: he touched the Source. It explains. ;)

Comment: Follow Simulacra & Simulation!

Comment: Didn't Neo first stop the machine weapons in The Matrix Reloaded, even before Revolutions? ("Something's different. I can feel them.")

Comment: @Null: Normally I'm reluctant to accept late answers, but you provided good support and documentation that made it a solid answer - and that's not easy to do with The Matrix, since the producers were more worried about style than substance.

Comment: Related on M&TV: [Why did Neo have powers in the real world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/8370/44222)

Comment: I think the point of it isn't "this is the real world," but "is this the real world." It goes back to the Architect saying that, as long as people feel that they have a choice, they won't think about the fact that all their choices are part of the same system.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The explanation given within the films is that Neo (as the One) has a special connection to the Source which allows him to control machines in the real world. Neo asked the Oracle how he was able to stop Sentinels in the real world and she gave him the answer:

> Neo: Tell me how I separated my mind from my body without jacking in. **Tell me how I stopped four sentinels by thinking it.** Tell me just what the hell is happening to me.
>
> Oracle: **The power of the One extends beyond this world. It reaches from here all the way back to where it came from.**
>
> Neo: Where?
>
> Oracle: The Source. That's what you felt when you touched those Sentinels. But you weren't ready for it. You should be dead, but apparently you weren't ready for that, either.
>
> <sub>***The Matrix Revolutions***</sub>

Neo was able to destroy the machines' weapons in *The Matrix Revolutions* in the same way. The films never explain exactly how Neo was able to control the machines in the real world, but it's worth noting that Neo was designed by the machines to carry machine code that enabled him to perform the function of the One. As explained by the Architect:

> The function of the One is now to return to the Source, allowing a temporary dissemination of **the code you carry**, reinserting the prime program.
>
> ...
>
> Your 5 predecessors were, **by design**, based on a similar predication - a contingent affirmation that was meant to create a profound attachment to the rest of your species, facilitating the function of the One.
>
> <sub>***The Matrix Reloaded***</sub>

We know machine code carried within a human body can affect the real world because of Smith's control over Bane in the real world. Thus, the code carried by the One undoubtedly gave Neo a connection with the Source in the real world as well.

The biggest question is how Neo manages to communicate orders via the Source in the real world, and the films don't explain how. Presumably he communicates wirelessly using his head jack. Zion's use of EMPs should disable the head jack, but the EMPs apparently only disable head jacks temporarily: humans can't be connected to the Matrix *during* an EMP blast but they can re-enter the Matrix *after* the blast, and Smith/Bane is put in a coma by his EMP blast in *The Matrix Reloaded* but eventually regains consciousness. Machines like Sentinels are permanently disabled by EMPs, but evidently the human body acts as a "battery" to re-start the head jack.

---

As an aside, the Matrix-within-a-Matrix (MWAM) theory is an understandably popular fan theory which easily explains how Neo controlled the machines in the real world. However, it suffers from several notable inconsistencies with known facts. For example:

1. Neo's powers in the real world are much more limited than his powers in the Matrix. In the Matrix he can fly, stop bullets, endure incredible acceleration, bring Trinity back from death, etc. But in the real world he can only affect machines, he can't fly (otherwise why would he need Niobe's ship to get to the Machine City?), he is easily and permanently injured (blinded) in his fight against Smith, and -- most notably -- he is unable to save Trinity from death. If the "real world" is just another Matrix there's no reason why Neo wouldn't be just as powerful in it.
2. The [Zion Archives](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Zion_Archives) depict the history of the [Machine War](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Machine_War) and the creation of the Matrix. If MWAM is true then the machines would have deliberately provided the Zion Archives to Zion. But the story told in the Zion Archives portrays the machines in a very bad light and includes some [very graphic scenes of human suffering caused by the machines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GA1C.png) and the [seemingly pointless detonation of a nuclear weapon by the machines *after* the humans had already surrendered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83512/31936). If the machines deliberately provided the Archives to Zion, they would have omitted those scenes and portrayed a story in which it was all the humans' fault for pre-emptively attacking the Machine City and scorching the sky.
3. In the final scene of *The Matrix Revolutions*, the Architect tells the Oracle that she played a "dangerous game" by breaking the cycles of the Ones and bringing about peace with Zion. But if MWAM is true, there was no danger nor purpose to the Oracle's plan -- the humans are no closer to escaping the outer Matrix of the "real world". And there would have been no reason for the Oracle and the Architect to have that conversation amongst themselves in the first place.
4. The machines cooperate with Neo to defeat Smith and as a result end the war with Zion. They act as if they are really threatened by the loss of their one power source. But if the "real world" was another Matrix the machines wouldn't care if Smith took over the Matrix -- the humans in the "real world" would still be providing power for the machines in the "really real world" regardless of the status of the Matrix.
5. [Humans appear as green code in the Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etTEo.png) but [only the machines have gold code in the real world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALgqw.png). If the "real world" was just another Matrix with gold instead of green code then humans and the surroundings should also look like gold code. What we see is exactly consistent with what we would expect if everything machine-generated appears as code and the real world is reality -- everything in the Matrix as appears as code but only the machines themselves appear as code in the real world.
6. Scenes in the Matrix have a green tint but scenes in the real world do not.

Okay, but what if the "real world" is a Matrix controlled by *different* machines? In other words, what if the machines we see in the films were themselves products of Supermachines which control the Matrix of the "real world"? Presumably the machines in the films would just be another level of control for the Supermachines and the machines wouldn't be aware of the Supermachines; the machines would think that the "real world" was real and not just another Matrix. This would explain some things like why the machines acted threatened by the loss of their power source in the "real world", but there are still inconsistencies with this Supermachine theory. For example:

1. The alleged Supermachines would have full control over the "real world"/"outer Matrix" and should be able to suppress Neo's ability to see the machines as gold code in the "real world". They apparently *can* prevent him from seeing anything else as gold code in the real world (e.g. other humans, who would still be simulations and thus appear as code in the "outer Matrix"). So why can't they prevent him from seeing the machines, too? Allowing Neo to see the machines as gold code would seriously undermine the usefulness of the "outer Matrix". The Supermachines *wouldn't* allow it, if they existed.
2. Similarly, the alleged Supermachines should be able to prevent Neo from controlling Sentinels in the "real world". The Supermachines certainly have an incentive to do so since they would want to do everything possible to help their machines win the war and keep the humans bottled up in the "inner Matrix". Again, the fact that the Supermachines are apparently unable to do this despite having full control of the "outer Matrix" gives us reason to believe that they don't exist.
3. As with the regular MWAM theory, the alleged Supermachines have no reason to provide the humans with the Zion Archives, which portray the machines brutally killing the surrendered humans. This only serves to fan the flames of hatred against the machines. From the perspective of the Supermachines it's preferable that, upon possible defeat of the machines, the humans enter into a truce with the machines as they did at the end of *The Matrix Revolutions*. That way the humans would just be content to live in the "real world", thinking that they'd already escaped the Matrix. Giving the humans access to the Zion Archives just makes a truce between the humans and machines less likely.

The Supermachine MWAM theory is a complicated theory which assumes that there is another race of machines controlling *another* Matrix (and possibly more) which is completely unknown to both the humans and the machines. In contrast, the dialogue from the films suggests that Neo communicates wirelessly with the machines in the real world, and only a few minor assumptions are required to explain how that's possible: that Neo's head jack is able to communicate wirelessly with the machines in the real world, and that the head jack can be rebooted after an EMP by its human "battery". By [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), the MWAM theory is less likely to be true.

Both versions of the MWAM theory also suffer from another, out-of-universe problem: if MWAM is true then all the events in the entire Matrix franchise are ultimately meaningless. The story starts with the humans imprisoned in multiple Matrix levels, a lot of things happen, and the story ends with the humans imprisoned in multiple Matrix levels.

Comment: Points 1-6 work on the assumption that the same machines built both levels of the Matrix, and do not work in the case that the machines inside the outer Matrix are unaware that they're in a Matrix.  On point 7, I understood that final scene in my answer to be a hint that we in real life are in the outer Matrix, with the optimistic message that it's possible to go even higher.

Comment: re point #2: Considering that the entire "Humans are a battery" thing goes against some of the most basic and fundamental laws of physics, we ***know*** beyond any shadow of a doubt: Everything the people of Zion know is full of lies, half-truths and machine created propaganda.

Comment: Controlling machines is one thing, and exploding them in an instant is another.  It is not shown that any of those machines carry explosives. How can someone simply explode them? And if so, he could just destroy them all, including the ones in Zion. For wireless communication, why does the distance even matter?

Comment: -1, despite some good points at the top, those arguments against the MWAM theory are pretty terrible.

Comment: @DCShannon *shrug* My answer was good enough to steal the acceptance from the MWAM answer.

Comment: @Null One is supposed to leave an explanatory comment after downvoting. You seem offended for some reason. If you have some reason why I'm wrong and those are great arguments, feel free to share it. Otherwise, I have no idea what you're doing right now. The acceptance is from one person. The upvotes tell a different story. Either way, this is one explanatory comment from one person. Is there something else you want from me? If not, just delete this comment. Probably the indignant retort, as well.

Comment: @DCShannon The vast majority of the upvotes on the MWAM answer were given before I posted my answer (it had a 3 1/2 year head start). The MWAM answer has also received more downvotes (7 to 2 as of now). Your comment is that my arguments are "pretty terrible", so my point is simply that others (including the OP) disagree with *you*.

Comment: *If the "real world" is just another Matrix there's no reason why Neo wouldn't be just as powerful in it.*

Except it's all about belief, and Neo is only powerful in the Matrix because he believes he is in the Matrix. When not in the Matrix, Neo has no reason to think he is in another Matrix so he believes he is in the Real World and would not believe he can break the rules.

Comment: Its worth noting that in the train station Nero seems to have no supernatural powers (yet that's a sub layer of the matrix), and your other reasons are based on what you think the machines want: and need to maintain the primary matrix. All your reasons could simple be explained by the machines maintaining the illusion for the upcoming years. I neither agree with MWAM or 'real world', I'm merely pointing out there is no way to prove either

Comment: And yet your answer is now much lower than the other answer. So, yes, your arguments were bad, and being conceited about it rather than responding to the actual counterclaims being made was a bad idea.

Comment: @trlkly As I said before, the other answer had a 3 1/2 year head start and a high score before I answered. The other answer provides only a speculative fan theory and fails to provide the explanation given in the films. Also, I *did* address the counterclaims that the machines we see in the films also control the "real world Matrix" in the [second revision of my post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105138/revisions).

Comment: @Null "Neo's powers in the real world are much more limited than his powers in the Matrix. In the Matrix he can fly, stop bullets,"etc... He can only do those things in the matrix because he _believes_ he can, because Morpheus convinces him he is living in a simulation. Remember, at first he couldn't do any of those things, until he started to believe. However, he also believes in a "real" world outside of the matrix, and he believes that when he is in the "real" world he can't do any of those amazing things because those things are impossible in the real world. He believes the spoon is real.

Comment: @Matt if you believe that the machines control which powers Neo has in what he assumes to be the real world and limit those powers to “keep up the illusion”, then why did they give him special powers in the “real world” in the first place? That would be like them begging him for discovering the truth.

Comment: @BrandonL he discovered that he can control/disable the machines, without first believing that the world is not real. He can see without his eyes. All without believing that he’s in a virtual reality. And now, you’re saying, the reason he can’t do other things is because it requires him to believe first?

Comment: Dude, ***WE*** are he Supermachines.  Or maybe the writers of the *Matrix* movies are.    Of course everything that happens in the movies can follow any rules they want -- in this case, that Neo can control them machines in the (movie) real world.

Answer (score 119):

One of Morpheus's first lines references Alice in Wonderland.  But, just how deep *does* the rabbit hole go?

I am of the opinion that Zion and the rest of the real world isn't actually the real world.  Humans are rebellious by nature, so what the Architect said about Zion needing to exist makes sense.  But as long as the humans believe they escaped from the Matrix, why does it need to be real?

Remember what Cypher said in the first movie?  As I recall, it was quite a popular quote for a while:

> Well you have to.  The image translators work for the construct program.  But there's way too much information to decode the Matrix.  **You get used to it. I...I don't even see the code. All I see is blonde, brunette, red-head.**  Hey, you uh... want a drink?

Why does that matter?  Well, remember this scene from the end of Matrix Revolutions, Neo walking through Machine City with his eyes wrapped up?  At that point, Neo had also learned/figured out how to see the code, and no longer needed his eyes:

("Real" world)
[image: real world]

(Seeing the underlying code/structure)
[image: underlying code]

So while Neo may have gotten one level closer to reality, he wasn't there yet.

[Image source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX3qLIwHoUo)

Comment: Ouch.  Now my brain hurts!

Comment: I'd be quite interested to learn why I got a downvote for this...

Comment: @Izkata The Architect is trying to discredit your work.

Comment: You are saying that Machine city was also not real.. Means, we never saw real machines?

Comment: +1: I thought this was where the movies were going, and the third movie would be Noe leading the lads out of the Zion VR, leaving the tantalizing question "Are they really out now?". Man was I ever disappointed by the last one, it managed to ruin the 2nd one for me too. [Too bad they never made any sequels](http://xkcd.com/566/)

Comment: @Izkata - I did not DV, but the MWAM (Matrix Within a Matrix) isn't anywhere near a confirmed correct truth, merely one popular fan theory. So perhaps that's why you were DVed.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier haha, funny xkcd. But I *do* like the sequels, all of them. If you think about the consequence of each movie and then compare it to the next one, you can see the difference. Revolutions I think is in particular revolutionary (again), if you think about it... ah it's called that!

Comment: While I think your answer is entertaining and well-constructed, I don't think there was any direct evidence in the movies that the real world was not in fact real, and the final onion layer of reality.  I think they were implying that Neo had control over some aspects of physical reality.  Including being able to see like Mohadeeb and control machines.

Comment: @MarkRogers: Well, what he does in the "real" world isn't really compatible with any natural law I ever encountered. However, it *is* indeed a strong indicator, that by the end of *Revolutions* he could see past the façade of the so-called "real" world just as he could see past the one of the Matrix in the first film. You might even go out on a limb and claim that when he appears to have died, he finally got one layer up --- alone.

Comment: Yeah I take it to mean that his power partly transcended the coded reality and was closer to that of a religious prophet.  Neo was transcending into some kind of god/prophet/martyrhood.  I do think that the Wachowskis brothers (almost said Coen) deliberately made it vague to bring up questions about the nature of reality.

Comment: @MarkRogers You're getting fantasy in my hard scifi  =o_0=

Comment: @Izkata - Lol, my apologies.  If it's any consolation I think your way would make a better story, I just think the brothers had the urge to merge into the story some more directly religious elements. Probably in an attempt to get some of that Star Wars multi-religion-inspired force goodness, that keeps fans captivated.

Comment: Christopher Nolan would be proud!

Comment: Your image with the gold code actually works against the MWAM theory. Only the machines are in gold code, but *everything* in the Matrix -- machines/programs, humans, buildings, etc. -- has green code. If the "real world" was just another Matrix we'd expect everything to appear in gold code in it.

Comment: I downvoted because the MWAM fan-theory has been quite comprehensively debunked. Although fan-theories (like the Jar Jar = A Sith) are amusing, they shouldn't be promoted as objective truth.

Comment: Null's point is important in debunking this. While Neo can see Smith after he's blinded (and sees him as Smith and not Bane), he can't see anything else and has to feel his way back into a chair when he re-joins Trinity in the hovercraft. This makes it extremely clear that Neo can only see Machine-related objects in the real world.

Comment: @Ellesedil That point isn't helpful in debunking anything. *Smith doesn't exist in the real world*. Answering the phone didn't inject Bane with nanobots or something. There is no physical structure inside of Bane that would have allowed Neo to see him. Hell, Neo's eyes were burnt out. Even if there was *something* physical for him to see, how could he see it? How did the data that Smith is inside Bane get from the 'real' world into Neo's brain? Either he is still jacked-in somewhere, or, the machines were exposing that data to him. If they were, where did *they* get that data from?

Comment: @Null What makes you think that if MWAM is true everything should be gold? Assume for a second MWAM is true. Neo's program, like everyone else's, doesn't have access to any of that data. Due to some sort of error or bug created by the Smith virus, some of the data Neo about the MWAM is exposed to Neo. Because it is a bug, his program doesn't get all the data, or the data is corrupted. This corruption makes it gold instead of green. Or, the MWAM is all gold, but he is only seeing some of it, because he should see none and there is a bug.

Comment: In the first Matrix, we are told a blatant lie that the humans believe; they are batteries. We are told that "if you accept reality, isn't it just as real?"  We are told that "how do we know this is what stuff really tastes like, all we have is our experience". In the second movie, we are told Zion is "at the Earth's core". We see someone's brain being taken over with a phone call. In the last movie, we see Neo using TK on machines and seeing like he can in the Matrix. There is lots of evidence that there is a MWAM; they hit you over the head with it. You can choose to accept it, or not.

Comment: What if the Gold Matrix isn’t a level *above* the Green Matrix but rather in *parallel*, with passages back and forth?

Answer (score 67):

Ok... to me this seems pretty simple. Neo is able to affect things in the matrix that normal people can't - he has escalated privileges, superuser access even above that of the Agents. Why shouldn't he be able to affect other parts of the machine infrastructure beyond the matrix simulators?

Then the only question is how are his wishes communicated to the machines? Well, he still has a machine-implanted jack in his skull - who knows whether it contains some kind of wireless backup link?

Yeah there's no evidence I know of in the movies for this, but it's certainly a simpler explanation than a whole nother level of simulated reality.

Comment: This feels most right to me. It even neatly explains why Neo could see the real world as code, given that the machines themselves would have code based information on all of the real world (Google Earth, Maps and Street View are already nicely accomplishing this).

Comment: Great answer.  Note that the writers originally intended the machines to be using humans as *processing* power; the power of the One is the ability to see and use the parts of the machine OS running in his own brain.

Comment: This suits my interpretation that as the movies go, Neo becomes more machine, and Smith becomes more human. Smith gets emotions, free will, steps into the real world. Neo gets wifi (can get in and out of the Matrix without a hard line).

Comment: Brian, this is the inverse of Occam's razor. Occam said "Don't multiply entities unnecessarily". Roughly "Don't make it have more thingies than it needs". Saying "There is only the Matrix" reduces the amount of entities and complications. Even saying "Humans in the Matrix see what they want to see", totally finished any issue with the movie.

Comment: An additional argument for this is that in the Matrix Neo could use his "telekinetic" powers on just about anything, but in the real world he could *only* stop machines like the squiddies. Likewise, in the Matrix he could see everything as code, in the real world he could *only* see machines and A.I.s (including Bane, because Agent Smith had taken over his brain). And he couldn't fly in the real world, which would have been enormously useful in reaching the machine city; nor could he do crazy gravity-defying kung fu movies, the fight with Bane was presented as a much more realistic brawl.

Comment: In addition to Hypnosifl comment, we know that plugged-in humans inside a ship can be actively connected to the matrix while the ship is flying. This implies that the connection is made over the air (wi-fi, electromagnetism, more advanced techno, etc.). So clearly, **machines infrastructures can be accessed over the air**. But humans still needed a seat with a plug and a computer as an interface to manage the connection. Neo seems the only one able to connect without that interface: we may hypothesize that due to his escalated privileges, he doesn't need any interface other than his brain.

Comment: Explain how a human being can be used as a battery; explain how a city can exist at the Earth's core.  A simple explaination that leaves things inconsistent does not pass Occam.

Comment: Occam's Razor would have told Neo to take the blue pill because the alternative explanation would be too ludicrously complicated to be true.

Comment: @Wildcard Occam's Razor says "don't multiply entities without necessity”, not "don't multiply entities".

Comment: This is actually a correct answer.

Answer (score 61):

There are a couple of in-universe theories that have been written about before (see [#4 here](http://www.cracked.com/article_19266_5-movie-fan-theories-that-make-more-sense-than-movie.html)).

> We've previously told you about a popular interpretation which holds that the "real" world of Zion is still part of the Matrix; Keanu had just moved up to another level of simulation, like in Inception.

But this [more elaborate theory](http://www.matrix-explained.com/)  is more interesting in my opinion.

> Zion is a Matrix-like simulation, but one made by humans for the purpose of creating better machines. In this scenario, Neo and his "enlightened" fellow humans were actually machines all along, and the baffling, recursive fight scenes they experienced in Matrix Reloaded were software implanted by the humans designed to teach them to understand human pain.

The movie canon doesn't hint at either of theories; although they aren't directly refuted. Unfortunately, the real answer is probably out-of-universe: **the Wachowskis brothers made a Lucasian blunder** and wrote in something into the plot that doesn't make sense within the universe they'd previously created.

Comment: -1 I'm sure it cannot be more far from being a blunder. Let alone a "Lucasian" one. If you think about it, it's totally not necessary to include Neo stopping machines like bullets, neither is the whole Architect thing, the whole trilogy could do just fine without them; but the idea is pursued consequentially.

Comment: What exactly is a "Lucasian blunder"? This answer is basically the only Google result that includes this phrase.

Comment: It’s not a term with any prior usage I know of. I intended it to mean in later works (e.g. the second two Matrix movies or Star Wars prequels) adding things that don't make sense. The SW example would be the demystification of the force. Basically creating a situation where you want to add something in a new film that contradicts your previous work but putting it in anyway and either trying to retcon it in or ignoring the issue.

Comment: Strangely enough, I found [another instance of "Lucasian"](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2014/03/modeling-vladimir-putin.html), but in that case I think it refers to [*Robert* Lucas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_critique), not George.

Answer (score 12):

This is ***a lot easier*** than what you guys have articulated. ***Think of Neo as a machine's version of A.I.***

Neo is a pod human. All pod humans are created by the machines. Since he's the one, the way he was created by the machines allows him to do things (i.e. fly and stopping bullets) in the Matrix that no other human can do.

The only way he can do the ^ isn't because his RSI in the Matrix grants him "master user status," it's because his ***physical body*** was uniquely created when the machines made him. Therefore, the reason he can do things in the Matrix that others can't is because the machines made his physical body differently from those of other humans and that physical distinction allows him to also do things ***outside of the Matrix*** (i.e., in the real world) that others can't do (i.e., the ability to see the energy machines have and stop them, presumably through wireless powers).

***Think of Neo as a machine's version of A.I.:***

Lastly, to analogize it, think of Neo as a machine with A.I., the machines are humans, and the pod humans are thoughtless machines (like a dish-washing machine or a lamp).

The machines use humans to help them live (similar to why humans, generally, created machines) and the machines created A.I. (in this case, Neo) as another means to survive (in this case, to make sure the Matrix is fail-proof).  Though humans created A.I. to allow them to survive, but screwed them over in the end, the same happened when the machines created Neo. Just like A.I. f@@@ed humans over, Neo f@@@ed the machines over because he's not like every pod human they created; he's got self-control, just like A.I.  ***Hence Neo used his "outside the Matrix" powers, which were granted to him by the machines, against his creators, just like the A.I. machines used their powers (in this case, intelligence), which were granted to them by humans, to rebel against their human creators.***

Comment: But his genetic material is still human.  Even though his physical means of conception where carried out by the machines, there still would have had to have been donor sperm and egg from a human, making him created the same as you or I.

Comment: @Monty129 You're assuming nothing was done to the genetic material.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it may be something telepathic.  From the scene where he got kicked back into the matrix and had to get out.  He developed the ability to affect the machines.  It even goes back further to when he jumps into Mr. Smith.  Mr. Smith later says something along the lines of I became a part of you and vice versa.  It first showed itself when he killed the squids but it is more impressive when he blows up all the missles

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps being in the real matrix helped to develop his abilities. Now developed, they work out of the Matrix too.

Answer (score 4):

Another theory, based on the expanded universe of the Matrix Online game: just like when he was in "digital" coma, his consciousness was held in the digital world and the body in the physical world, when he's awaken some part of himself may still be in the matrix at all time.

This would explain why he would still retain some degree of power, only on machines of course, while being disconnected: he may not be able to directly communicate with his "digital counterpart", but the digital counterpart may well be aware of everything about his physical counterpart via the machines (eg, when the missiles are launched towards Neo in his flying ship towards Deus Ex Machina, the digital counterpart is already informed and can work to take down the missiles).

This is kind of confirmed by Matrix Online, where the corrupted RSI (residual self image) of Neo [re-appeared](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Matrix_Online) even through Neo was dead (since the events of the game happen after the movies), and it was in the process of being repaired before the game ended, thus implying that the digital counterpart could be separated and even survive the physical counterpart.

However, this does not explain how Neo could "feel" the machines, but it may well be just a residual feeling from his sentiment that some part of him has been detached to stay inside the Matrix, just like a [phantom limb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_limb).

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler than Inception kind of stuff. As shown in movie *somehow* he remained connected with Matrix even in the real world unlike others. He felt the machines because they were a part of Matrix as well.

His indirect connection with machines allowed him to interact with them. He stopped them by thinking about it (just like he did in simulation) and was able to sense them (see them without eyes) because of his connection.

When Smith occupied the brain of Ben, he would have been able to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Neo is a cyborg, he was created by machines - as the chosen one. Or maybe he's just genetically modified, as he has no parents (they were machines). There is no facts behind that, though, but remember that he almost doesn't have life in the matrix - no family or friends, it seems as he was reset and plugged into the matrix a while ago .

Answer (score 1):

You could actually already ask this question about the way he shut down the Sentinels at the end of Reloaded, and the answer is probably the same. While one explanation surely is [the uber-Matrix mentioned in another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11493/769), a much simpler explanation comes to my mind:

As the Architect revealed, Neo's being The One (or at least, *someone* becoming the One every now and then) is part of the Matrix programme. Therefore it is not unlikely that the machines actually still have a weak wireless connection to the Redpills and thus know what Neo is attempting to achieve - and his purpose is

> to betray those who trusted him by selecting 23 others to rebuild Zion instead of saving everyone (of course, he refused to do so)

so it is conceivable the machines actively helped him, even his meeting the Architect especially once

> Smith wrecked havoc,

which would also explain why he suddenly could "see" again after having being blinded.

Of course, you could even manage without a wireless connection, when you assume that in order to be The One, Neo had a slightly different Physiology (maybe something about [Delta Brainwaves](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Why_of_Fry)) that allowed him to *actually* first emit and later detect electromagnetic waves independently of his eyes...

Answer (score 0):

I have to say - Tinch's argument is the one I've seen here which differs from my own, but shows a lot of originality in its analysis and I think it's interesting.

> The machines use humans to help them live (similar to why humans, generally, created machines) and the machines created A.I. (in this case, Neo) as another means to survive (in this case, to make sure the Matrix is fail-proof).

While I could see this being justified in-part due to canon, where the Architect explains that the "one" is a systemic-anomaly that basically embodies all the leftover subconscious rebellion from the Human psyche, and a depository for incompatible algorithms. Which must be re-inserted into the Matrix so that people will be able to "choose," once again, if even on an unconscious level (as he explained about the Oracle, or "Jesus'" idea). The answer was simple to me even from the first time I saw the conclusion to the Trilogy.  Remember, Agent Smith was able to supersede the matrix by taking that phone call - thus using the *digital-translation* mechanism of the telephone, in order to get into that other character's mind - becoming his consciousness.  This brought Agent Smith **out** of the Matrix, since while **inside** the matrix a consciousness is virtual, anyway (whether you're Human **OR** machine). So why couldn't it work the other way around?  It's not coincidental that at roughly this same time in the second installment, Neo has grown so accustomed to the "sense" of how the Matrix operates (after-all, being able to see in code and everything), that in a way dualistic to how Smith escaped, he is actually able to use Matrix-like powers against them from **OUTSIDE** the virtual-construct.

Keep in mind, the Matrix was constructed by these very machines - so it's not surprising that while Smith has the ability to transcend the "virtual world" into the real, but the flip-side of that is Neo being able to transcend the "real" world's limitations directly through his accumulated interface with the nature of these same machines. Remember, when he entered Smith's avatar in the dramatic conclusion of the 1st movie?  Well, I believe that's a **CLUE** to what the Architect would ultimately confirm in the second movie, and that is Neo is somehow integral to the survival of the Matrix. So there's no reason to object to the possibility that this fundamental connection *couldn't* supersede that virtual form - after-all, the minds behind the Matrix have a physical basis **OUTSIDE** of it as much as the actors jacking into the Matrix do as well. It's the opposite of bleeding in your chair when you get punched too many times while connected to the program, basically.

It's no coincidence, therefore, that Smith in Bane's body ends up lying in the medical-bay directly (and oppositely-positioned) from Neo, after this manifestation of his intrinsic connection to the Machines outside in reality actually drains him of all his energy - hey, I'd be exhausted too after something like that.