# Why Did Neo Think His Powers Would Work Outside the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

After asking about [how Neo could use his powers outside the Matrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/in-the-matrix-revolutions-how-does-neo-stop-the-machine-weapons-in-the-real-wo), it left me thinking about this from another point of view.

While there is a question about how Neo could use his powers outside the Matrix, there is another question that comes with that: How did Neo know his power would work on the weapons the Machines were launching at him and the ship?

Neo knew the difference between inside and outside the Matrix, and knew the difference between reality and the fantasy world in the Matrix.  On the surface, he had no reason to expect his powers to work outside the Matrix.  Something must have given Neo a reason to believe his powers worked in the real world.

What make him think his powers would work against the Machines outside the Matrix?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Remember his line:

> Something's different. I can feel them.

He feels that "the real world" is different than before and it reminds him of The Matrix. Additionally: At that point, there was really nothing to lose; the sentinels were about to kill them. Wouldn't you give it a shot if you had a hunch?

Comment: "He feels that "the real world" is different than before and it reminds him of The Matrix"

I always assumed he did something in the matrix that allows him to give commands to the machines in the real world. Where does this info come from?

Comment: @Parrotmaster Literally the quote preceding that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the machines were outside agents of the Matrix, perhaps he was simply able to exploit their connection to it. This might also be how he could sense their presence.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this quote:

> Morpheus:
>   That you are a slave, Neo.
>   Like everyone else you were born into bondage.
>   Into a prison that you cannot taste or see or touch.
>   A prison for your mind.

that Neo's mind has been freed by this point in the story means the question is actually: "why would Neo NOT think this" and if the movie is a metaphor for the nature of reality, and the Matrix within the story is a metaphor of reality, then why would Neo freeing his mind not affect reality?

Comment: I don't understand the relevance between your point here and Neo thinking his powers would work outside the matrix.

Comment: @Edlothiad if Neo comes to the real world without his mind, then it might make sense for having previously freed his mind having no effect in the real world. since all evidence suggests that Neo had a mind, freed it, and brought it to the real world: his mind should be freed in the real world.

Comment: @Edlothiad is there a strong argument for the mind being imprisoned by discreet, world-specific prisons that must be individually escaped? or can the operating assumption be that freeing one's mind is context-independent?