# Will there be another iteration of The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

At the end of *The Matrix Revolutions* it appears Neo died (or maybe not, [according to this masterpiece answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/did-neo-die-in-the-end-of-the-matrix-trilogy)) and created peace between humans and machines. There are arguments for both sides on whether Neo lived or died.

My question though, relates more to the conversation between the Architect and the Oracle at the end of *The Matrix Revolutions*.

> Oracle: Well, now, ain’t this a surprise.
>
> Architect: You’ve played a very dangerous game.
>
> Oracle: Change always is.
>
> Architect: **Just how long do you think this peace is going to last?**
>
> Oracle: **As long as it can.**
>
> {Architect starts walking away}
>
> Oracle: What about the others?
>
> Architect: What others?
>
> Oracle: The ones that want out.
>
> Architect: Obviously, they will be freed.
>
> Oracle: I have your word?
>
> Architect: What do you think I am? Human?
>
> ...
>
> Sati: Look, look! *points at sunrise*
>
> Oracle: Just look at that! Beautiful! Did you do that?
>
> Sati: *nods* For Neo.
>
> Oracle: That’s nice. I know he’d love it.
>
> Sati: Will we ever see him again?
>
> Oracle: **I suspect so. Someday.**
>
> <sub>***The Matrix Revolutions***</sub>

I interpret this to mean the peace wont last forever, a new Matrix iteration will one day ensue and there will be a **need for a new One.**

**Will there be another iteration of the Matrix, with a Zion, humans unknowingly living in a simulation, and humans fighting machines?**