# How did Neo know that the "reality" Morpheus told him was the real world was not actually just another simulated reality?

Tags: the-matrix, the-animatrix

How did Neo know that the "reality" Morpheus told him was the real world was not actually just another simulated reality? I mean if he believed Morpheus' explanation on simulation isnt it logical for him to assume that the real world was also simulated. Wouldnt it be the perfect prison designed by the machines. Design the prison world and a world for those who think they have escaped.

Comment: He might have suspected the possibility that the "Matrix" was a Matrix-within-a-Matrix (MWAM) at first, but later events would have provided evidence against such a hypothesis. [My answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105138/31936) has points against the MWAM theory at the end of it. It's an interesting theory to ponder but it  contradicts too many other things in the films.

Comment: They don't know, and can't know.  So it wouldn't make a fun movie?

Comment: From *our* perspective it is an obvious theory, perhaps encouraged by the fact that the true explanation (that the movies are at their core from the fantasy genre rather than science fiction) generates a certain amount of cognitive dissonance. From Neo's point of view?  Too scary to think about, and it isn't like he could do anything about it if it were true anyway.  If he were inclined towards that sort of paranoia, he wouldn't be The One, and more importantly (from our perspective) he wouldn't be the main character. :-)

Comment: @Null, I have read your other answer and am thinking the events of Matrix Reloaded better fit the above theory of a Matrix within a Matrix. Neo can see the code of the machines as long as he within the matrix. Him being able to control the sentinels outside the 'first' matrix points to that. This idea would probably lead to a better climax in the third movie...like the dream within a dream thingy in the movie 'Inception'

Comment: How do *we* know our reality is not simulated?

Comment: I addressed the fact that Neo can see the code of the machines in the real world -- the fact that he cannot also see non-machines in the real world is actually evidence that the real world is not an "outer Matrix". As for being able to control the sentinels, that's directly addressed by the films and is in the beginning of my linked answer.

Comment: If the machines could simulate a perfect Matrix, they'd have no need to simulate a lower level.

Comment: @JDoe That question is probably the second-least interesting question in philosophy, right after the question of free will.